# Does php-frm make PHP run faster?

Tags: php, fastcgi, php-fpm

As I understand it, [php-fpm](http://php-fpm.org) makes PHP pages respond faster by managing a farm of pre-loaded PHP interpreter processes so the end user doesn't experience the overhead of initialising the PHP subsystem, but once a PHP page starts executing it takes just as long as it would under "regular" CGI.  It's a bit like running a Perl script under [mod_perl](http://perl.apache.org) - the interpreter doesn't run any faster because its bound into the web server executable, it just start up faster.

Am I right, or is there something subtle going on under the hood that makes it run faster overall?  The reason for asking is that I have a PHP application that I want to run periodically (I run a 'wget' for its URL every X seconds).  I'm not bothered about the response time because its periodic, but I am bothered about the execution time.

Comment: This question might be more appropriate in ServerFault as its about optimisation rather than programming.  I've flagged it to the moderator for a judgment.  In the meantime, please answer if you know!

Comment: Sounds like it doesnt matter so much in your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you PHP code itself will not run faster, it's still the same interpreter. You might have a small latency profit compared to normal CGI, but who runs normal CGI anyway? ;-)

Another small help could be the code caching, but that's only really useful if the script is run often.

Comment: Code cacheing might be a help here.  The PHP page is invoked very frequently - once every 5 to 15 seconds - so being able to "copy" the page execution image in some way would be beneficial.  With mod_perl, for example, I know I can pre-load libraries before the fork, so if I could do a similar trick with PHP then I'd avoid the overhead of multiple interpreter read-in phases.  Is this possible?

Comment: I found this - http://thephp.cc/news/2013/06/php-5-5-out-of-the-box-bytecode-cache - which seems to be talking about this - http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php - is this what you're referring to?

Comment: Indeed. So if you're using 5.5, that benefit is gone. The problem with APC and 5.4- was that each new process would have it's own cache, it would not shared compiled code between those. That's one thing you can solve with php-fpm.

Comment: I don't understand your comment about the benefit "going" with 5.5.  The article says "OpCache is built by default but disabled by default" so I don't get the benefit immediately out-of-the-box - I have to tweak the config file first.  And I'm pleased it's "built by default" as it means I shouldn't have to mess around building from source on my Ubuntu server - it should be there in the deb file already.

Comment: Ah true that. Haven't used 5.5 myself yet, didn't know it was disabled by default.